# Returning response of spring controller to the angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I am trying to pass the response of my rest controller when a user tries to signup the form to my java script whether username is available or not basing upon the returned statement by the spring controller.However i tried to use model attribute in my spring controller.What is the way that i capture this in my js. From servlet perspective it is done as we have out.write  how can it be done with spring.

My Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/checkUserName", headers = "Accept=application/json")
public org.weber.nag.model.UserRegistration checkUserName(@RequestBody org.weber.nag.model.UserRegistration userReg, Model model) {
    userDao.getAllUsers(userReg);
    System.out.println(userDao.getAllUsers(userReg));
    model.addAttribute("success", userReg);
    return userReg;
}
```

AngularJS

```
   var formData = {
                 'userName'  : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.userName
          };
         var response =$http.post('http://localhost:8081/Weber/user/checkUserName', formData);
         response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

             var cntrlMessage = $('#message');
                message = cntrlMessage;
                //alert(message);
            alert(message);
             $scope.list.push(data);
         });
         response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "User name already exists.");
         });
```

updated Spring Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserRegistrationControllerImpl{

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/checkUserName", headers = "Accept=application/json")
public String checkUserName(@RequestBody org.weber.nag.model.UserRegistration userReg, ModelMap model) {
    userDao.getAllUsers(userReg);
    System.out.println(userDao.getAllUsers(userReg));
    String message = userDao.getAllUsers(userReg);
    model.addAttribute("message", message);
    return message;
}
}
```

I tried to hit the rest controller with $http it worked well how can i take the repose of my rest controller say user available/user not available back to my js as an alert.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to use Ajax to do the job done.

Then your Ajax success method is expecting to accept text response.

With that being said:

1. From your controller just return any String/text you want to display as a legitimate answer: `user available/user not available`
2. Annotate your controller with `@ResponseBody` that will tell Spring to return the String answer inside the HTTP response. So your Ajax success method will accept that HTTP response, with `user available/user not available` message.
3. Make sure you're actually getting that String in your js file using `console.log`

   ```
   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/checkUserName")   
   @ResponseBody
   public UserRegistration checkUserName(@RequestBody UserRegistration userReg, Model model) {
       userDao.getAllUsers(userReg);
       System.out.println(userDao.getAllUsers(userReg));
       model.addAttribute("success", userReg);
       return userReg;
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes i had already annotated my spring controller with @RestContorller. Tried to return a string response but no luck its not displaying in the console.I will post update module in my post .

Comment: I talked about  `@ResponseBody` not  `@RestContorller`

Comment: RestCotroller will take care of Responsebody too if i am correct.Anyways i will add the annotation you suggested :).Even though i add the responsebody still its not showing any alert in my js but when i hit the controller i can see " user available/user not available "my eclipse console

Comment: If you're hitting the controller successfully, then the problem is with your Angular.js code.  It seems you're failing to hit the success method on your js file.

Comment: Yea that is true the reason i am not getting any alert but i have changed the .js but the same issue its not showing the alert.

Comment: Then this is an Angular.js question now.

Comment: Yes i have edited my js but the response i am getting from the spring controller always returns error message in my js and moreover i changed my method to return model and view then it is returning some response to my js. i have updated them again in the above post.

Comment: From the controller you suppose to return a String, a text answer, this is how Ajax works

Comment: Ok if i return a string also the response i.e. the alert is always from error response of my JS.